How to apply normal/bump maps?
I applied a bump map to dent the geometry a bit but it seems like the program is taking the edges instead of adding them as a hole. What am I doing wrong?



What I would like to achieve is something like in the last image

You have connected the Normal Map node to the Displacement input. That's bad. Connect it to the Normal input of the Principled BSDF node. For the Displacement input you need a Displacement node ;-)

Oh, of course, the censored image texture should be a blue Normal map (OpenGL encoded) if you want to use a normal map -OR- a greyscale displacement/height map for the Displacement node. The height map you also can use with a Bump node. Last but not least, you should use Non-Color for the Color Space option. You have set it to the default sRGB.

You have to connect the Normal Map node to the Normal input in the BSDF node.
The displacement output is reserved for the Displacement node.
What you could also try is to change the material settings to display Bump + Displacement and see if it helps.

...and set the Color Space to Non-Color.

Thank you very much! it worked, at least as a bump detail that i wanted.
